# Ethereum Mist MongoDB port

Tags: mongodb, port, ethereum

After Running the **Ethereum Mist,** I can't connect to the *mongodb*. I use the Robomongo 0.9.0-RC10(https://robomongo.org).

Can anyone tell me mongodb's port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Ethereum, but as far as MongoDB is concerned you might want to try the default port, which is port 27017.

See the [official documentation on MongoDB's default ports](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/) for default ports of MongoDB.